# Is there a library to apply a Mean Curvature Blur in Python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, filter, blur

In GIMP there is a blur called Mean Curvature. I‘d like to apply a filter like that on a picture in a python script but don‘t find a library/module that implements this algorithm. Does anybody know one?
Thank you!

I searched for an implementation of a Mean Curvature Blur in python but didn’t find one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions asking for library recommendations are off-topic on here as you can see when you take the [tour] or read about [ask].

Comment: Adding `gimp` tag might attract the right people. Adding a screenshot of the GIMP dialog and your settings and the effect might help.